# iOS 9 - NSUserDefault Not Set

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsuserdefaults

I am having a slight issue with the `NSUserDefault` in Swift 2.0.

I am doing the following operation:

```
    let standardUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    standardUserDefaults.removeObjectForKey(key)

     NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
or 
     standardUserDefaults.synchronize()
```

My problem is that if I close the app after doing that, the key is not being deleted.

Previously I did not have the `synchronize()`, and after looking on the forum , I realized that you need to force the action if you need it to be done immediately rather than let apple do that periodically.

I also added the `synchronize()` in the `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` in order to try and see but it still does not work.

So it is weird, if I wait after I perform the action, and check, the key is beeing deleted.
If I wait or not after I perform the action then just force quit the application (sliding up the app), when I load back the app, the key is still there, even though the `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationDidBecomeActive` are being called and the `synchronize()` is being called.
If I just put the application in the background, same behavior :-/

I am not sure what I am missing here ?

---

Okay so here more details :

Okay so I perform the action in a ViewController:

```
@IBAction func doneAction() {

<DO SOME STUFF>

let standardUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
standardUserDefaults.removeObjectForKey(key)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

}
```

Nothing fancy :-/ 
I do not understand why if I close or put the app in the background the operation is not being apply or discarded ?

It is implemented in view controller :

```
class reviewViewController: ViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate, State {
```

**EDIT :**
  @HongWei The NSUserDefaults are already wrapped up and nothing is calling that guy anymore during the send to background of the app.

I tried that :

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(
            NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject("TEST 1"), forKey: "TEST2").
```

I then put the app in background after and then I check in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method when I bring the app back up:

```
if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("TEST2") as? NSData, wrapper = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data) as? String{
    print(wrapper);
}
```

I see `"TEST 1"` being printed.

I then call the delete method :

```
let standardUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
standardUserDefaults.removeObjectForKey("TEST2")
```

I then send the app back in the background, and wake the app back up , I check in the breakpoint in the same `applicationDidBecomeActive` The value is being printed ... I am using my phone and not the simulator ... It just does not make sense.

I also try instead of deleting to do that instead :

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(
            NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject("TEST 3"), forKey: "TEST2").
```

In the `applicationDidBecomeActive` the output is `"TEST 1"` .... It seems like the modification is not being applied :-O

Comment: Where do you implement that code?

Comment: It's the simulator problem of caching the memory first. It only happens in xcode and should not happen on a device. Did you check on a device?

Comment: Hello, yes I was reading about that as well, unfortunately, it happens on my device too :-( I push the build through xCode 7.1 straight to my phone .

Comment: @julien you would need to show the rest of your code and where it is implemented. BTW calling synchronize it is not needed and won't make a difference.

Comment: @julien there are a few things you can try

1.  Check that the key you use for both removing and accessing is the same
2.  You might have re-introduced a value for the key somewhere else in the code base. Try to wrap NSUserDefaults operations in one class so you can track accesses easily
3.  Instead of removing the object for key, try setting a hard coded junk value and see if you see the same junk value when you load back the app.

Comment: I wonder what kind file I/O pattern you see when you profile your app with Instruments. NSUserDefaults eventually needs to hit file system to complete saving. Is there any mechanism preventing file system access? File Protection? I'm just guessing around... I think you should profile to discover a hard proof.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(registrationDictionary)
```

as it's required by [NSUserDefaults Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/registerDefaults:).

> you need to call this method each time your application starts